# How to do page break when exporting google sheet into PDF

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-pdf, page-break

I want to export the current google sheet data into pdf page but I do want a page break at row 10 so that any data after row 10 goes on to the next page. This means there will be multiple pages for more data. I do not want to print all data on one page. The final pdf file should have multiple pages for data that crosses row 10 in the google sheet

```
var saveToRootFolder = false
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Export all sheets', 'exportAsPDF')
    .addItem('Export all sheets as separate files', 'exportAllSheetsAsSeparatePDFs')
    .addItem('Export current sheet', 'exportCurrentSheetAsPDF')
    .addItem('Export selected area', 'exportPartAsPDF')
    .addItem('Export predefined area', 'exportNamedRangesAsPDF')
    .addToUi()
}
function _exportBlob(blob, fileName, spreadsheet) {
  blob = blob.setName(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E4:G4').getValue())
  var folder = saveToRootFolder ? DriveApp : DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).getParents().next()
  var pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob)
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID");
  pdfFile.moveTo(folder);
  
  // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to open <a href="' + pdfFile.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + fileName + '</a></p>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(80)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export Successful')
}
function exportAsPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var blob = _getAsBlob(spreadsheet.getUrl())
  _exportBlob(blob, spreadsheet.getName(), spreadsheet)
}
function _getAsBlob(url, sheet, range) {
  var rangeParam = ''
  var sheetParam = ''
  if (range) {
    rangeParam =
      '&r1=' + (range.getRow() - 1)
      + '&r2=' + range.getLastRow()
      + '&c1=' + (range.getColumn() - 1)
      + '&c2=' + range.getLastColumn()
  }
  if (sheet) {
    sheetParam = '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()
  }
  // A credit to https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70
  // these parameters are reverse-engineered (not officially documented by Google)
  // they may break overtime.
  var exportUrl = url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, '')
      + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
      + '&size=A4'
      + '&portrait=true'
      + '&fitw=true'       
      + '&top_margin=0.2'              
      + '&bottom_margin=0.2'          
      + '&left_margin=0.2'             
      + '&right_margin=0.1'   
      + '&scale=3'       
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
      + '&pagenum=UNDEFINED' // change it to CENTER to print page numbers
      + '&gridlines=true'
      + '&fzr=FALSE'      
      + sheetParam
      + rangeParam
      
  Logger.log('exportUrl=' + exportUrl)
  var response
  var i = 0
  for (; i < 5; i += 1) {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      headers: { 
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      },
    })
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 429) {
      // printing too fast, retrying
      Utilities.sleep(3000)
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
  
  if (i === 5) {
    throw new Error('Printing failed. Too many sheets to print.')
  }
  
  return response.getBlob()
}
function exportAllSheetsAsSeparatePDFs() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var files = []
  var folder = saveToRootFolder ? DriveApp : DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).getParents().next()
  spreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(function (sheet) {
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet)
    
    var blob = _getAsBlob(spreadsheet.getUrl(), sheet)
    var fileName = sheet.getName()
    blob = blob.setName(fileName)
    var pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob)
    
    files.push({
      url: pdfFile.getUrl(),
      name: fileName,
    })
  })
  
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to open PDF files</p>'
      + '<ul>'
      + files.reduce(function (prev, file) {
        prev += '<li><a href="' + file.url + '" target="_blank">' + file.name + '</a></li>'
        return prev
      }, '')
      + '</ul>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(150)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export Successful')
}
function exportCurrentSheetAsPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  
  var blob = _getAsBlob(spreadsheet.getUrl(), currentSheet)
  _exportBlob(blob, currentSheet.getName(), spreadsheet)
}
function exportPartAsPDF(predefinedRanges) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  
  var selectedRanges
  var fileSuffix
  if (predefinedRanges) {
    selectedRanges = predefinedRanges
    fileSuffix = '-predefined'
  } else {
    var activeRangeList = spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList()
    if (!activeRangeList) {
      ui.alert('Please select at least one range to export')
      return
    }
    selectedRanges = activeRangeList.getRanges()
    fileSuffix = '-selected'
  }
  
  if (selectedRanges.length === 1) {
    // special export with formatting
    var currentSheet = selectedRanges[0].getSheet()
    var blob = _getAsBlob(spreadsheet.getUrl(), currentSheet, selectedRanges[0])
    
    var fileName = spreadsheet.getName() + fileSuffix
    _exportBlob(blob, fileName, spreadsheet)
    return
  }
  
  var tempSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(spreadsheet.getName() + fileSuffix)
  if (!saveToRootFolder) {
    DriveApp.getFileById(tempSpreadsheet.getId()).moveTo(DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).getParents().next())
  }
  var tempSheets = tempSpreadsheet.getSheets()
  var sheet1 = tempSheets.length > 0 ? tempSheets[0] : undefined
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(tempSpreadsheet)
  tempSpreadsheet.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone())
  tempSpreadsheet.setSpreadsheetLocale(spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetLocale())
  
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedRanges.length; i++) {
    var selectedRange = selectedRanges[i]
    var originalSheet = selectedRange.getSheet()
    var originalSheetName = originalSheet.getName()
    
    var destSheet = tempSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(originalSheetName)
    if (!destSheet) {
      destSheet = tempSpreadsheet.insertSheet(originalSheetName)
    }
    
    Logger.log('a1notation=' + selectedRange.getA1Notation())
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(selectedRange.getA1Notation())
    destRange.setValues(selectedRange.getValues())
    destRange.setTextStyles(selectedRange.getTextStyles())
    destRange.setBackgrounds(selectedRange.getBackgrounds())
    destRange.setFontColors(selectedRange.getFontColors())
    destRange.setFontFamilies(selectedRange.getFontFamilies())
    destRange.setFontLines(selectedRange.getFontLines())
    destRange.setFontStyles(selectedRange.getFontStyles())
    destRange.setFontWeights(selectedRange.getFontWeights())
    destRange.setHorizontalAlignments(selectedRange.getHorizontalAlignments())
    destRange.setNumberFormats(selectedRange.getNumberFormats())
    destRange.setTextDirections(selectedRange.getTextDirections())
    destRange.setTextRotations(selectedRange.getTextRotations())
    destRange.setVerticalAlignments(selectedRange.getVerticalAlignments())
    destRange.setWrapStrategies(selectedRange.getWrapStrategies())
  }
  
  // remove empty Sheet1
  if (sheet1) {
    Logger.log('lastcol = ' + sheet1.getLastColumn() + ',lastrow=' + sheet1.getLastRow())
    if (sheet1 && sheet1.getLastColumn() === 0 && sheet1.getLastRow() === 0) {
      tempSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet1)
    }
  }
  
  exportAsPDF()
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)
  DriveApp.getFileById(tempSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true)
}
function exportNamedRangesAsPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var allNamedRanges = spreadsheet.getNamedRanges()
  var toPrintNamedRanges = []
  for (var i = 0; i < allNamedRanges.length; i++) {
    var namedRange = allNamedRanges[i]
    if (/^print_area_.*$/.test(namedRange.getName())) {
      Logger.log('found named range ' + namedRange.getName())
      toPrintNamedRanges.push(namedRange.getRange())
    }
  }
  if (toPrintNamedRanges.length === 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No print areas found. Please add at least one \'print_area_1\' named range in the menu Data > Named ranges.')
    return
  } else {
    toPrintNamedRanges.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.getSheet().getIndex() - b.getSheet().getIndex()
    })
    exportPartAsPDF(toPrintNamedRanges)
  }
}
```

Comment: *Breaks are not available in Google Sheets or Slides* -- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893?hl=en&ref_topic=1361463 I'm afraid you will need one more feat: to put your table in Document. Or wait @Tanaike to invent some workaround.

Comment: Hi there! Besides what @YuriKhristich said, you could potentially develop an Apps Script solution that creates a new sheet with your desired rows, and then convert that to PDF. Would that be a valid solution in your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I developed an example script to test the approach described in my comment. I'll leave it here for future reference, but feel free to leave a comment if you have any doubt about it. This is the final script:

```js
function exportRowsToPDF() {
  var importantRows = [2, 13, 14, 15, 19]; // Exported rows
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var originalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet("TEMP", 10);
  var maxColumn = originalSheet.getLastColumn();

  for (var i = 0; i < importantRows.length; i++) {
    tempSheet.appendRow(originalSheet.getRange(importantRows[i], 1, 1, maxColumn)
      .getValues()[0]);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "TEMP") {
      sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }

  DriveApp.createFile(spreadsheet.getBlob().setName("Exported Sheet"));

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].showSheet();
  }

  spreadsheet.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
}
```

You can modify the script to export any particular rows, but I used five of them for testing. This script will create a new sheet on your spreadsheet, and it will copy any relevant row there. Then, it will hide every sheet minus the newly created one. After that it will export the spreadsheet as a PDF blob directly to your Drive. Finally, it will reset the spreadsheet to the original state (by removing the created sheet and unhiding every other sheet). This code uses the same methods as your example, but write to me if you want to clarify any point.